# Net::SSH stuck at a password prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this function, it works when I pass the correct username and password, and when I deliberately pass wrong password I get stuck at     `Password:` prompt.

```
def perform(sensor_params)
    @hostname = "10.0.10.100"
    @username = "root"
    @password = "root"

    @cmd = "id"

    begin
      ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password)
      res = ssh.exec!(@cmd)
      ssh.close
      puts res
    rescue
      puts "Unable to connect to #{@hostname} using #{@username}/#{@password}"
    end
 end
```

Any idea on how I could just spit the message "Unable to connect" when the passed password is incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: Missing a double quote on the password command.

Comment: Not sure what you aim at with "how I could just spit the message". With `non_interactive` set and removing the `rescue` block (or narrowing it down), the method should just raise a `Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed` exception.

Answer (score 7):

According to the docs you can pass `:non_interactive => true` to instead raise an authentication error.

Comment: I have actually tried using :non_interactive => true, when I do, I keep getting authentication error even tho I'm passing the correct password

Answer (score 1):

Passing `:number_of_password_prompts => 0` fixed my issue issue.

Comment: Which is strangely equivalent to setting [`non_interactive`](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/master/lib/net/ssh.rb#L212), as mentioned by Frederick Cheung.

Comment: When I use non_interactive I got Argument Error
ArgumentError: invalid option(s): non_interactive @EricPlaton

But :number_of_password_prompts => 0 fixed my issue.